# ios7 - Custom UItabbar has a gap in the bottom

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

Im trying to create a custom UITabbar using images for the selected and unselected states.

this is my code:

```
if ([UIImage instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(imageWithRenderingMode:)]) {

    tab_01_on_image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tabbar_on_01"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    tab_01_off_image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tabbar_off_01"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

} else {
    tab_01_on_image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Tabbar_on_01"] ;
    tab_01_off_image = [UIImage imageNamed:N@"Tabbar_off_01"] ;

}

[[[self.tabBarController.tabBar items] objectAtIndex:index] setFinishedSelectedImage:tab_01_on_image withFinishedUnselectedImage:tab_01_off_image];
```

This image shows the problem, the red color is the gap:

[image]

*EDIT to add the code to create the UITabbar*

```
self.tabBarController = [[BaseTabbarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[navControll1, navControll2, navControll3, navControll4, navControll5];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

I appreciate any help you guys can offer

Comment: how high Tabbar_on_01?

Comment: the @2x image is 128x100px
I also tried with 128x98px and got the same problem.

Comment: Is your view designed with Interface Builder, or do you create it programmatically?

Comment: programmatically zbMax

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code creating the tabbar please?
By the way, follow this guidelines page for your icon dimension : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/BarIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH21-SW1

Comment: zbMax, I edited my question to show how the tabbar is created

Answer (score 6):

I finally found the solution. Changing the imageInsets of each tabbarItem did the trick.

```
tabBarItem1.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
tabBarItem2.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
tabBarItem3.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
tabBarItem4.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
tabBarItem5.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
```